# Not able to load jQuery Calendars Datepicker (islamic) in openerp v7

Tags: jquery, calendar, datepicker, openerp-7

I would like to add jQuery Calendars Datepicker (islamic) into openerp. so that I have added
some required JavaScript into `__openerp__.py file`.

```
    "static/lib/jQuery_calendars/jquery.plugin.js",        
    "static/lib/jQuery_calendars/jquery.calendars.js",
    "static/lib/jQuery_calendars/jquery.calendars.picker.js",
    "static/lib/jQuery_calendars/jquery.calendars.plus.js",        
    "static/lib/jQuery_calendars/jquery.calendars.islamic.js"
```

But at this point I am facing error like Uncaught

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function and it comes from jquery.calendars.js file 
and at _validate: function(year, month, day, error)
```

Can you please help me how can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This error occur due to name conflict with some other function of jquery in openerp. i found the solution. please use below condition in jquery.calendars.js at line no 340.

- if (typeof(year)!='number' && typeof(year.year())=='number')